# Enable <select> <option> after clicking radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a group of 2 radio buttons and 2 classes with 'select' options.

When you click on the first radio button the select options from class1 enable when you click on the second the select options from class must be enable.

```
<input type="radio" onchange="myFunction1()" name="enable" >1  <br>
    <input  type="radio" onchange="myFunction2()" name="enable">2 <br>


            <select name="Reden"> 
        <option class="one" value="1" disabled >1</option>
        <option class="one" value="2" disabled >2</option>
        <option class="one" value="3" disabled  >3</option>
        <option class="two" value="4" disabled>4</option>
        <option class="two" value="5" disabled>5</option>
        <option class="two" value="6" disabled>6</option>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction1() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0].disabled = true;
        document.getElementsByClassName("one")[1].disabled = true;
        document.getElementsByClassName("one")[2].disabled = true;
        document.getElementsByClassName("two")[0].disabled = false;
        document.getElementsByClassName("two")[1].disabled = false;
        document.getElementsByClassName("two")[2].disabled = false;
        }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0].disabled = false;
        document.getElementsByClassName("one")[1].disabled = false;
        document.getElementsByClassName("one")[2].disabled = false;
        document.getElementsByClassName("two")[0].disabled = true;
        document.getElementsByClassName("two")[1].disabled = true;
        document.getElementsByClassName("two")[2].disabled = true;

        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hey Marvin, what problem are you having? You told us the end game, but what's going wrong?

Comment: Why is disabled on the option and not the select?

Comment: Firstly I would recommend to separate php and html as much as possible. It makes it much easier to read and maintain your code. Secondly, you could implement the desired result with javascript or with php by submitting the form after selecting a radio input. I prefer javascript for such things.

Comment: update your code with your js code

Comment: php is not really relevant here. Post rendered html along with the javascript you tried

Comment: @msg Thanks for the comments! Ik have update my post :)

Comment: @AndrewLohr There is nothing happen when i select a radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain javascript is not my forte so it might not be pretty but it works.

```js
var select = document.getElementById("Reden")
var enabler = document.getElementsByName("enable")
var allOptions = select.getElementsByTagName("option");

// Add a listener for the radio changes
for (var i = 0, len = enabler.length; i < len; i++) {
  enabler[i].addEventListener('click', optionToggle);
}

// Disables all options and reenables those that match the value of the radio
function optionToggle() {
  filterOptions = select.getElementsByClassName(this.value)
  select.value = ""
  setDisabled(allOptions, true)
  setDisabled(filterOptions, false)
}

function setDisabled(targetList, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < targetList.length; i++) {
    targetList[i].disabled = value;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" value="1" name="enable">1 <br>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="enable">2 <br>


<select id="Reden">
  <option class=1 value="1" disabled="">1</option>
  <option class=1 value="2" disabled="">2</option>
  <option class=1 value="3" disabled="">3</option>
  <option class=2 value="4" disabled="">4</option>
  <option class=2 value="5" disabled="">5</option>
  <option class=2 value="6" disabled="">6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: WoW! Thkn you so much :)

Comment: @Marvin fixed a bug with the `select` remaining with a now disabled value after change

Answer (score 0):

If you want use your code you to have add 
this two lines

```
document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0].selected="selected";
```

and

```
document.getElementsByClassName("two")[0].selected="selected";
```

In this situation the user when click on one radio button get default value 1 or 4.
below there is an example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
           function myFunction1() {
       document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0].disabled = false;
       document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0].selected="selected";
       document.getElementsByClassName("one")[1].disabled = false;
       document.getElementsByClassName("one")[2].disabled = false;
       document.getElementsByClassName("two")[0].disabled = true;
       document.getElementsByClassName("two")[1].disabled = true;
       document.getElementsByClassName("two")[2].disabled = true;
       }
   </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
           function myFunction2() {
       document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0].disabled = true;
       document.getElementsByClassName("one")[1].disabled = true;
       document.getElementsByClassName("one")[2].disabled = true;
       document.getElementsByClassName("two")[0].disabled = false;
       document.getElementsByClassName("two")[0].selected="selected";
       document.getElementsByClassName("two")[1].disabled = false;
       document.getElementsByClassName("two")[2].disabled = false;

       }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="radio" onchange="myFunction1()" name="enable" >1  <br>
      <input  type="radio" onchange="myFunction2()" name="enable">2 <br>


              <select name="Reden">
          <option class="one" value="1" disabled >1</option>
          <option class="one" value="2" disabled >2</option>
          <option class="one" value="3" disabled  >3</option>
          <option class="two" value="4" disabled>4</option>
          <option class="two" value="5" disabled>5</option>
          <option class="two" value="6" disabled>6</option>

</body>
</html>
```